# How to compute the integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am trying to do the following integration
$$\int_0^\infty d\rho \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(\rho \cos\theta)-1}{\rho^{1+\alpha}}\sin^{d-2} \theta d\theta$$
where $\alpha\in(0,2), d\geq 2, d\in \mathbb{N}$.

The solution should be something consisting of Gamma functions $\Gamma(\cdot)$ but I don't know how to compute it.

Comment: CAS says: $\int _0^{\pi }\int _0^{\infty }\frac{(\cos (\rho  \cos (\phi ))-1) \sin ^{d-2}(\phi )}{\rho ^{1+\alpha }}d\rho d\phi =\frac{\cos \left(\frac{\pi  \alpha
   }{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (-1+d)\right) \Gamma (-\alpha ) \Gamma \left(\frac{1+\alpha }{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{d+\alpha }{2}\right)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To evaluate the integral
\begin{equation}
I=2\int_0^\infty d\rho \int_0^{\pi/2 }\frac{\cos(\rho \cos\theta)-1}{\rho^{1+\alpha}}\sin^{d-2} \theta \,d\theta
\end{equation} 
one may notice that
\begin{equation}
\cos(\rho \cos\theta)-1=-2\sin^2\frac{\rho}{2} \cos\theta
\end{equation} 
Then, changing $x=\frac{\rho}{2} \cos\theta$, the integral can be written as a product of two integrals:
\begin{equation}
I=-2^{2-\alpha}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{1+\alpha}}\, dx\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{d-2}\theta\cos^\alpha\theta\,d\theta
\end{equation} 
From the integral representation of the Beta function [(DLMF)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E2),
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{d-2}\theta\cos^\alpha\theta\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{B}\left( \frac{d-1}{2},\frac{1+\alpha}{2} \right)
\end{equation} 
We define
\begin{equation}
J(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2 xt}{x^{1+\alpha}} \,dx
\end{equation} 
then the first integral is $J(1)$. A differentiation wrt the auxiliary variable $t$ gives
\begin{align}
J'(t)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2xt}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx\\
&=2^{\alpha-1} t^{\alpha-1}\int_0^\infty u^{-\alpha}\sin u\,du\\
&=2^{\alpha-1} t^{\alpha-1}\Gamma\left( 1-\alpha \right)\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(1-\alpha) \right)
\end{align} 
where the integral representation [(DLMF)](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E7) was used.
Then, noticing that $J(0)=0$,
\begin{align}
J(1)&=2^{\alpha-1} \Gamma\left( 1-\alpha \right)\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2}(1-\alpha) \right)\int_0^1t^{\alpha-1}\,dt\\
&=2^{\alpha-1} \frac{\Gamma\left( 1-\alpha \right)}{\alpha}\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \right)\\
&=-2^{\alpha-1}\Gamma\left( -\alpha \right) \cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \right)
\end{align} 
Finally,
\begin{align}
I&=\operatorname{B}\left( \frac{d-1}{2},\frac{1+\alpha}{2} \right)\Gamma\left( -\alpha \right)\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \right)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left( -\alpha \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{d-1}{2} \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{1+\alpha}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left( \frac{\alpha+d}{2} \right)}\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\alpha \right)
\end{align}
as noticed in the comment by @Mariusz Iwaniuk